# WPF Tree doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, treeview

Could you tell me why I can't see subItems?

I've got winforms apps and I added my wpfusercontrol:ObjectsAndZonesTree

ServiceProvider is my webservice. Adn method to get listofcountires with subitems works properly (i get countires, regions from this countires, provinces etc...)

```
 ElementHost elementHost = new ElementHost
                                          {
                                              Width = 150,
                                              Height = 50,
                                              Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                                              Child = new ObjectsAndZonesTree()
                                          };


            this.splitContainer3.Panel1.Controls.Add(elementHost);
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="GroupView" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ServiceProvider:Country
}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ServiceProvider:Region}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ServiceProvider:Province}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

XAML.CS

```
 public ObjectsAndZonesTree()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadView();
        }

        private void LoadView()
        {
            GroupView.ItemsSource = new ServiceProvider().GetListOfObjectsAndZones();

        }
```

class Country:

```
public class Country
    {
        string _name;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }
        string _code;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Code
        {
            get { return _code; }
            set { _code = value; }
        }

        string _continentCode;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ContinentCode
        {
            get { return _continentCode; }
            set { _continentCode = value; }
        }

        public Region[] ListOfRegions
        {
            get { return _listOfRegions; }
            set { _listOfRegions = value; }
        }

        private Region[] _listOfRegions;

        public IList<object> Items
        {
            get
            {
                IList<object> childNodes = new List<object>();
                foreach (var group in this.ListOfRegions)
                    childNodes.Add(group);

                return childNodes;
            }
        }



    }
```

Class Region:

public class Region
    {

```
private Province[] _listOfProvinces;
        private string _name;
        private string _code;

        public Province[] ListOfProvinces
        {
            get { return _listOfProvinces; }
            set { _listOfProvinces = value; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get {
                return _name;
            }
            set {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public string Code
        {
            get {
                return _code;
            }
            set {
                _code = value;
            }
        }

        public string CountryCode
        {
            get { return _countryCode; }
            set { _countryCode = value; }
        }

        private string _countryCode;

        public IList<object> Items
        {
            get
            {
                IList<object> childNodes = new List<object>();
                foreach (var group in this.ListOfProvinces)
                    childNodes.Add(group);

                return childNodes;
            }
        }
}
```

It displays me only list of countires.

Comment: @Phenevo: Are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *Region* `DataTemplate` needs to be a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to support nested items (SubItems). You also need to specify it's `ItemsSource`.

```
<TreeView Name="GroupView" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ServiceProvider:Country}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ServiceProvider:Region}" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ServiceProvider:Province}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

So for example if you add *Cities* to your *Provinces* the changes in your XAML might look something like this.

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ServiceProvider:Province}" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ServiceProvider:City}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where your problem is, but I thought I would share you the best resource I've found when dealing with Treeview. Thoses extension methods saved me a lot of hassle :

http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET23

They transform any flat list into a Ienumerable of HierarchyNode using some nice lambda syntax. It is implemented with IQueryable, which means efficient even against a linq datacontext.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on Binding source class??

Plus you can check for binding exceptions in output window of visual studio.
It will help you understanding invalid bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need HierarchialDataTemplates instead of plain DataTemplates.

The others wrote everything, so I'll post some useful links:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/11/a-treeview-a-hierarchicaldatatemplate-and-a-2d-collection-walk-into-a-bar.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx